# How to permanently set the iOS Simulator to a different language than english

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I'm developing an app that mainly uses the German language. Because of that, I would like to have the iOS Simulator to be set to German language by default. If I start the iOS Simulator having the language of MacOS set to German, the Menu language of the Simulator is German, but the language 'inside' the simulated iOS is English. I know, that I can change the language within the simulated iOS. But thats not what I'm looking for, because after a reset of the simulator I have to set the language again, and also changing the simulated language seems to be very buggy in iOS 4.2 (frequently leading to hard crashes of MacOS).

Is there a way (maybe via the command line) to permanently change the default language of the simulator?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I have never experienced bugs or crashes when switching the language in the Simulator, for what it's worth. (And recently did a bunch for localization testing.) I hope you reported the crashes to Apple, because they probably aren't common.

Comment: @David: which system region format are you using, US or something from Europe? There is a bug that might be related: http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=1392405

Comment: I think I did only a little with German formats (which is of course different from German language). That bug reminds me of some real old Mac bugs I had to work around, with Swiss German formats.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

As seen in the iOS7 [TechTalks Video](https://developer.apple.com/tech-talks/videos/) "Hidden iOS Developer Gems", you can set two properties in the build scheme so that the simulator changes to your selected language and region:

[image: Build Schemes in Xcode 5]

That way you can also easily add multiple run schemes if you need to test different languages each time and quickly switch them before running.

---

Edit: As of Xcode 6, you can edit this information directly through the run schemes options. Just select "Application Language" and/or "Application Region".

[image: Xcode 6 Simulator Language and Region]

Comment: As of January 2014 this is the best answer

Comment: Just posting options for copy-pasting:
`-AppleLanguages (lan)
-AppleLocale lan_LAN`

Comment: Under "Options" now, in the same "Edit Scheme..." window, you can now pick "Application Language" as well as system region, from a drop-down of languages your app says it supports.

Comment: @denbec Hi, this does not seem to affect the localized price for in-app-purchases. I just changed both application language and region in the scheme but the SKProduct price locale is still USD while testing in sim. Any suggestions?

Comment: @sweepez I believe the currency depends on the iTunes Sandbox User. Don‘t know out of my head if you can log into an account within the simulator. But it‘s depended on the user account, not the language setting.

Comment: To open the Scheme: `Product - Scheme - Edit Scheme` - if you're using `Locale.current` in your app, you have to change the "Application Region" in the Scheme settings. Setting the "Application Language" actually didn't change anything for me, not even the app names on the home screen of the simulator (they were still in English).

Answer (score 3):

You could make yourself a script using ios-sim-locale to set simulator options if the locale settings are lost. See [ios-sim-locale](http://code.google.com/p/ios-sim-locale/wiki/Usage). This way you only would need to execute the script before starting the simulator.